# Prompting user to continue not working, java

Tags: java, loops, do-loops

I need help. I want to ask the user if he wants to try again, but something seems to be wrong with my code, because it's not working.

```
public class TotoAzul
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      int n1, n2, sum;
      String answer;
      do {

      System.out.println("Enter number 1: ");
      n1 = keyboard.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter number 2: ");
      n2 = keyboard.nextInt();

      sum = n1 + n2;

      System.out.println("Number 1\t" + "Number 2\t" + "Sum");
      System.out.println("__________________________________");
      System.out.println(n1 + "\t\t" + n2 + "\t\t" + sum);

      System.out.println("Enter yes to continue or any other key to end");
      answer = keyboard.nextLine();

      keyboard.nextLine();

      }
      while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));



}

   }
```

When I run it, it stores the user's answer, yet the program doesn't repeat. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `keyboard.nextLine();` after `n2 = keyboard.nextInt();` to accept and ignore the *dangling newline character* in the  inputstream left behind by call to `nextInt()`.

*When I run it, it stores the user's answer*  - Try printing what it has stored in the `answer` field then you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of `keyboard.nextLine();`.

```
keyboard.nextLine();
answer = keyboard.nextLine();
```

In your code answer is getting next line(i.e. `enter`), which comes into picture when you take value of n2 and press enter.

---

You can test your code by executing below code

```
System.out.println("Enter yes to continue or any other key to end");
answer = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Answer : " + answer);
System.out.println(keyboard.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      int n1, n2, sum;
      String answer = "Yes";

while (answer.equals("Yes"))
{
 System.out.println("Enter number 1: ");
      n1 = keyboard.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter number 2: ");
      n2 = keyboard.nextInt();

      sum = n1 + n2;

      System.out.println("Number 1\t" + "Number 2\t" + "Sum");
      System.out.println("__________________________________");
      System.out.println(n1 + "\t\t" + n2 + "\t\t" + sum);

      System.out.println("Enter yes to continue or any other key to end");
      answer = keyboard.nextLine();

      keyboard.nextLine();
}
```